# Xcode How can I know which subclass has my class?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

When I create a new file in Xcode I can specify a subclass of my new class. But when it is already created, how can I know which subclass has it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During compilation, you can type:

```
po [self class]
```

It will show you class of `self`. You can check class for any object currently in scope.

Answer (score 3):

You see that in the class definition / .h file, for example:

```
@interface BCFrequencyPlot : NSView
```

`BCFrequencyPlot` is a subclass of `NSView`.